# Recorrer 2 listas en java

Tags: java, string, bucle-for

```
    List<String> DiasSemana = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasSemana.add("Lunes");
    DiasSemana.add("Martes");
    DiasSemana.add("Miércoles");
    DiasSemana.add("Jueves");
    DiasSemana.add("Viernes");
    DiasSemana.add("Sábado");
    DiasSemana.add("Domingo");

    List<String> DiasTRabajo = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasTRabajo.add("Lunes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Miércoles");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Viernes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Domingo");

    for (String ds : DiasSemana) {
        for (String dt : DiasTRabajo) {
            if (ds.equals(dt)) {
                System.out.println("Trabaja : " + ds);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO Trabaja : " + ds);
            }
        }
    }
```

Llevo ya un rato intentando y no logro un resultado.
Quiero que partiendo de las listas obtenga como resultado

```
Trabaja : Lunes
No Trabaja : Martes
Trabaja : Miércoles
No Trabaja : Jueves
Trabaja : Viernes
No Trabaja : Sábado
Trabaja : Domingo
```

A mi se ocurrió hacerlo así. Si alguien puede corregirme o ilustrarme con una mejor manera les agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Qué versión de Java utilizas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a que por cada elemento de la lista `DiasSemana` estás recorriendo toda la lista `DiasTRabajo` y por cada elemento de esta última imprimes algo, ya que sea que trabajó o no. Esto no es correcto, porque para poder determinar si en la lista `DiasTRabajo` se encuentra el día analizado según la lista `DiasSemana` e imprimir si trabajó o no, debes recorrerla hasta que encuentres dicho día, o no, y en ese momento, cuando termines de recorrerla, es que debes indicar si trabajó o no. Por ejemplo:

```
    boolean found;
    for (String ds : DiasSemana) {

        found = false;
        for (String dt : DiasTRabajo) {
            if (ds.equals(dt)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            System.out.println("Trabaja : " + ds);
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO Trabaja : " + ds);
        }
    }
```

Si te das cuenta, la variable `found` la utilizó para ponerla como `true` si encuentro el día analizado. Si al salir del `for` anidado (el de adentro) `found` es true, pues indico que se trabajó y en caso contrario indico que no se trabajó y procedo a analizar el siguiente día de la semana.

El `break` lo utilizo para terminar la ejecución del `for` anidado si encuentro el día.

Comment: Muchas gracias.!
Me encontraba atorado en esa parte... 
Funciona perfecto

Comment: Por nada, me alegra que te haya servido!!

Answer (score 4):

Chicos respeto su solución pero no es necesario recorrer las dos listas con solo recorrer una basta, ya que los ArrayList poseen el método constains el cual devuelve un valor booleano si uno de los elementos que se le pasa esta en la lista a verificar, aqui mi solucion:

[Ver documentación Java.Util.ArrayList.contains](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm)

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> DiasSemana = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasSemana.add("Lunes");
    DiasSemana.add("Martes");
    DiasSemana.add("Miércoles");
    DiasSemana.add("Jueves");
    DiasSemana.add("Viernes");
    DiasSemana.add("Sábado");
    DiasSemana.add("Domingo");

    ArrayList<String> DiasTRabajo = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasTRabajo.add("Lunes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Miércoles");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Viernes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Domingo");

        for (String ds : DiasSemana) {
             System.out.println(DiasTRabajo.contains(ds) ? "Trabaja : " + ds :"NO Trabaja : " + ds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mejor esta solución que la aceptada como correcta

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera con tu ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String Dia = "";
    boolean check = false;

    List<String> DiasSemana = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasSemana.add("Lunes");
    DiasSemana.add("Martes");
    DiasSemana.add("Miércoles");
    DiasSemana.add("Jueves");
    DiasSemana.add("Viernes");
    DiasSemana.add("Sábado");
    DiasSemana.add("Domingo");

    List<String> DiasTRabajo = new ArrayList<>();
    DiasTRabajo.add("Lunes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Miércoles");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Viernes");
    DiasTRabajo.add("Domingo");

        for (String ds : DiasSemana) {
            check = false;
            for (String dt : DiasTRabajo) {
                    if (ds.equals(dt)) {
                        check = true;
                        Dia = ds;
                    } else {
                        Dia = ds;
                    }
            }
            if(check)
            {
               System.out.println("Trabaja : " + Dia); 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("NO Trabaja : " + Dia);
            }


        }
}
}
```

Listo.

Comment: Está bien que intentes aportar una solución, pero no puedes empezar tu respuesta con "Bueno no se si te entendí bien". En el caso de que tengas dudas debes aclararlas primero en la sección de comentarios de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar Java 8 también, ya que el código queda mas legible:

```java
diasSemana.forEach(
    (d) -> {
        String laborable = diasTRabajo.contains(d) ? " Trabaja" : " Libra";
        System.out.println(d + laborable);
    }
);
```

Comment: Recuerda que algunos no saben usar lambdas, así que una explicación mínima les ayudaría bastante